# How to use sleuth traceId to replace gateway logprefix

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

How to use sleuth traceId to replace gateway logprefix,

if we can do this, then we can get traceId easliy with `exchange.getLogPrefix()`

and gateway internal have the same traceId for logprefix

EDIT:
Spring Cloud Gateway log messages with request id as prefix, that is init in [DefaultServerWebExchange](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b4eb895927e55ba92917cc7522dc93606d84f442/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/server/adapter/DefaultServerWebExchange.java#L125)

Task `AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler` for example:

```java
    protected void logError(ServerRequest request, ServerResponse response, Throwable throwable) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(request.exchange().getLogPrefix() + formatError(throwable, request));
        }
        if (HttpStatus.resolve(response.rawStatusCode()) != null
                && response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)) {
            logger.error(LogMessage.of(() -> String.format("%s 500 Server Error for %s",
                    request.exchange().getLogPrefix(), formatRequest(request))), throwable);
        }
    }
```

which log message:

```
2022-02-23 20:38:29.844 ERROR [app,,] 4160 --- [ctor-http-nio-7] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [abc93ed7-6]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/"
```

the `[abc93ed7-6]` is log prefix, the whole gateway project use this.

if we can use sleuth traceId to repace it, it will be much easier

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Hi, already updated